# Android: image upload not working in s4

Tags: android, image, post, image-uploading, galaxy

I couldn't understand the problem in s4. In all other devices i can able to post images(encoded as base64 string) along with few more text parameters to server but in s4 it is not working.

When i try to post text parameters alone it is working.

If i add image in post parameter its is not adding in server (PHP script)

```
public class CreateListing extends Activity {
private TextView districtTv,pTypeTv, typeTv,tenureTv,bedroomsTv, bathroomsTv, facingTv, storeyHeightTv;
private EditText landSize, psf, title, block, streetName, unitNo, postalCode, price, description;
private com.evvo.landedhome.customfonts.LondonBetween landSizeTv;
private ProgressDialog processdialog;
private String district="0",landedType="0",propertyType="0",tenure="0",bedrooms="0", bathrooms="0",
        facing="0", storyHeight="0";
private JSONObject createList;
ArrayList<String> imgStringFile = new ArrayList<String>();
String thumbencodedString="";
ImageLoader galleryImageload;
DisplayImageOptions options;
LinearLayout galleryLayout,thumbLayout;
int count=0;
boolean thumb = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        setContentView(R.layout.create_listing);
        GlobalClass global = (GlobalClass) getApplication();
        galleryImageload = global.getImageLoaderObj();
         options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         //display stub image
         .showStubImage(R.drawable.agent_dp)
         //rounded corner bitmap
         .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10)) 
         .build();
         galleryLayout=(LinearLayout)(findViewById(R.id.showImagesLayout));
         thumbLayout=(LinearLayout)(findViewById(R.id.showthumbLayout));
        districtTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.listingDistrictSpinner));
        districtTv.setOnClickListener(listener);

        typeTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.LandedSpinner));
        typeTv.setOnClickListener(listener);
        pTypeTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.PropertyType));
        pTypeTv.setOnClickListener(listener);
        tenureTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TenureSpinner));
        tenureTv.setOnClickListener(listener);
        bedroomsTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.BedRoomsSpinner));
        bedroomsTv.setOnClickListener(listener);
        bathroomsTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.BathroomsValue));
        bathroomsTv.setOnClickListener(listener);

        facingTv =((TextView)findViewById(R.id.facingValue));
        facingTv.setOnClickListener(listener);

        storeyHeightTv=((TextView)findViewById(R.id.storeyValue));
        storeyHeightTv.setOnClickListener(listener);

        landSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landSizepinner);
        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceValue);

        //landSize.setOnKeyListener(keylistener);
        landSize.addTextChangedListener(tw);
        //price.setOnKeyListener(keylistener);
        price.addTextChangedListener(tw);

        psf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.psfValue);
        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.propertyTitle);
        block = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BlockNo);
        streetName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetName);
        unitNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unitValue);
        postalCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postalValue);
        description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descValue);
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backArrow)).setOnClickListener(listener);
        ((LondonBetween) findViewById(R.id.createLayout)).setOnClickListener(listener);
        landSizeTv = (com.evvo.landedhome.customfonts.LondonBetween) findViewById(R.id.landSizeStrTv);
        Advertisement advt = new Advertisement(CreateListing.this, (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.advtImage));
        advt.loadAdvertisement();
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.galleryPicker)).setOnClickListener(listener);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.thumbPicker)).setOnClickListener(listener);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private String getText(EditText tv){
    return tv.getText().toString().trim();
}
private boolean validateSuccess(){
    boolean flag = false;
    try{
        if(district.equals("0") || landedType.equals("0") || propertyType.equals("0") || tenure.equals("0") || 
                bedrooms.equals("0") || bathrooms.equals("0") || facing.equals("0") || storyHeight.equals("0") 
                || getText(title).equals("") || getText(postalCode).equals("") || getText(price).equals("") 
                || getText(description).equals("") || getText(landSize).equals("") || getText(psf).equals("")
                || getText(block).equals("") || getText(streetName).equals("") || getText(unitNo).equals("")
                ||thumbencodedString.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All fields are mandatory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(imgStringFile.size()==0)               {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Atleast one gallery image must be uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            flag = true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;
}
private void clearValues(){
    try{
        imgStringFile.clear();
        district = "0";
        landedType = "0";
        propertyType = "0";
        tenure = "0";
        bedrooms = "0";
        bathrooms = "0";
        facing = "0";
        storyHeight = "0";
        title.setText("");
        postalCode.setText("");
        price.setText("");
        psf.setText("");
        landSize.setText("");
        description.setText("");
        block.setText("");
        streetName.setText("");
        unitNo.setText("");
        districtTv.setText("Any");
        typeTv.setText("Any");
        pTypeTv.setText("Any");
        tenureTv.setText("Any");
        bedroomsTv.setText("Any");
        bathroomsTv.setText("Any");
        facingTv.setText("Any");
        storeyHeightTv.setText("Any");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  private   OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){  
            case R.id.backArrow:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.createLayout:
                if(validateSuccess()){
                    createNewListing();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.deleteImage:
                if(v.getTag(R.id.isthumb).toString()=="true")   {
                    thumbencodedString="";
                    ((LinearLayout)(findViewById(R.id.showthumbLayout))).removeView((View)v.getParent());
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.thumbPicker)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    imgStringFile.remove(v.getTag(R.id.imageid));
                    ((LinearLayout)(findViewById(R.id.showImagesLayout))).removeView((View)v.getParent());
                    count--;
                    if(count<3){
                        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.galleryPicker)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    Log.d("tag", v.getTag(R.id.imageid).toString());
                    Log.d("countval", count+"");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.thumbPicker:
                Intent thumbintent = new Intent();
                thumbintent.setType("image/*");
                thumbintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(thumbintent,"Select Picture"), Constants.SELECT_THUMB);
                break;
            case R.id.galleryPicker:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), Constants.SELECT_PICTURE);
                break;
            case R.id.listingDistrictSpinner:
                districtTv.requestFocus();
                Intent districtIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                districtIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.districts);
                districtIntent.putExtra("value", district);
                districtIntent.putExtra("Title","District");
                startActivityForResult(districtIntent,Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHDISTRICT);
                break;
            case R.id.LandedSpinner:
                typeTv.requestFocus();
                Intent landedIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                landedIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.Type);
                landedIntent.putExtra("Title","Landed Type");
                landedIntent.putExtra("value", landedType);
                startActivityForResult(landedIntent,Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHPROPERTYTYPE);
                break;
            case R.id.TenureSpinner:
                tenureTv.requestFocus();
                Intent tenureIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                tenureIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.Tenure);
                tenureIntent.putExtra("Title","Tenure");
                tenureIntent.putExtra("value", tenure);
                startActivityForResult(tenureIntent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHTENURE);
                break;
            case R.id.BedRoomsSpinner:
                bedroomsTv.requestFocus();
                Intent bedroomIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                bedroomIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.Bedrooms);
                bedroomIntent.putExtra("value", bedrooms);
                bedroomIntent.putExtra("Title","Bedrooms");
                startActivityForResult(bedroomIntent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHBEDROOM);
                break;
            case R.id.PropertyType:
                pTypeTv.requestFocus();
                Intent typeIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                typeIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.PropertyType);
                typeIntent.putExtra("value", propertyType);
                typeIntent.putExtra("Title","Type");
                startActivityForResult(typeIntent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_PROPERTY_TYPE);
                break;
            case R.id.BathroomsValue:
                bathroomsTv.requestFocus();
                Intent bathIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                bathIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.Bathrooms);
                bathIntent.putExtra("value", bathrooms);
                bathIntent.putExtra("Title","Bathrooms");
                startActivityForResult(bathIntent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_BATHROOM);
                break;
            case R.id.facingValue:
                facingTv.requestFocus();
                Intent facingIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                facingIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.Facing);
                facingIntent.putExtra("value", facing);
                facingIntent.putExtra("Title","Facing");
                startActivityForResult(facingIntent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_FACING);
                break;
            case R.id.storeyValue:
                storeyHeightTv.requestFocus();
                Intent storeyIntent = new Intent(CreateListing.this,ListPicker.class);
                storeyIntent.putExtra("ArrayId", R.array.StoreyHeight);
                storeyIntent.putExtra("value", storyHeight);
                storeyIntent.putExtra("Title","Storey Height");
                startActivityForResult(storeyIntent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_STOREY_HEIGHT);
                break;
        }
    }
};
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try{
        if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode==Constants.REQUESTCODE_SETTINGS){
            finish();
        }else if(resultCode==RESULT_OK ){
            int id = data.getIntExtra("Id" ,0);
            switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHDISTRICT:
                district=Integer.toString(id);
                districtTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.districts)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHPROPERTYTYPE:
                landedType=Integer.toString(id);
                landSizeTv.setText("Land Size");
                if(id==6){
                    landSizeTv.setText("Built In");
                }
                typeTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Type)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHTENURE:
                tenure=Integer.toString(id);
                tenureTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Tenure)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_SEARCHBEDROOM:
                bedrooms=Integer.toString(id);
                bedroomsTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Bedrooms)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_BATHROOM:
                bathrooms=Integer.toString(id);
                bathroomsTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Bathrooms)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_PROPERTY_TYPE:
                propertyType=Integer.toString(id);
                pTypeTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PropertyType)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_FACING:
                facing=Integer.toString(id);
                facingTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Facing)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_STOREY_HEIGHT:
                storyHeight=Integer.toString(id);
                storeyHeightTv.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.StoreyHeight)[id]);
                break;
            case Constants.REQUESTCODE_SETTINGS:
                createNewListing();
                break;
            case Constants.SELECT_PICTURE:
                ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.createListScroll)).fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                if(selectedImagePath!=null){
                    Log.d("selectedImagePath",selectedImagePath);
                    Log.d("selectedImageUri", selectedImageUri+"");
                    if(count<3){
                        imgStringFile.add(selectedImagePath);
                        count=count+1;
                        addedImageLayout(galleryLayout,"file://"+selectedImagePath, count,false);
                        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.galleryPicker)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if(count==3){
                        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.galleryPicker)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                }
                break;
            case Constants.SELECT_THUMB:
                ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.createListScroll)).fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                Uri thumbImageUri = data.getData();
                String thumbImagePath = getPath(thumbImageUri);
                if(thumbImagePath!=null){
                    addedImageLayout(thumbLayout,"file://"+thumbImagePath, count,true);
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.thumbPicker)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                thumbencodedString=base64String(thumbImagePath);
            break;
      }}    
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

public String base64String(String path){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    Log.d("path", path);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , baos);    
    byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray(); 
    Log.d("bytearray",buffer+"");
    //Log.d("base64 string", Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT));
    return Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);

}
public void addedImageLayout(LinearLayout parentLayout,String imgPath, int position,boolean thumb)
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    View imagesView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.added_image_layout, null);
    parentLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 15);
    ImageView thumbImage=((ImageView)imagesView.findViewById(R.id.gallerythumb));
    thumbImage.setTag(R.id.imageid, imgPath);
    galleryImageload.displayImage(imgPath, thumbImage,options);
    Button deleteButton=((Button)imagesView.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage));
    deleteButton.setTag(R.id.imageid, imgPath);
    deleteButton.setTag(R.id.isthumb, thumb);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    parentLayout.addView(imagesView,params);
}
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null)
    {
        //HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        //THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    else return null;
}
private void createNewListing(){
    try{
        if(ConnectionCheck.checkOnline(CreateListing.this)){
            if(processdialog==null){
                processdialog = ProgressDialog.show(CreateListing.this, "",  "Posting...", true);
            }else{
                processdialog.show();
            }
            GlobalClass global = (GlobalClass) getApplication();
            HashMap<String,String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postParam.put("propertyType", landedType);
            // 1. for sale, 2. for rent
            postParam.put("propertyCategoryType", propertyType); 
            postParam.put("title", getText(title));
            postParam.put("propertyTenure", tenure);
            postParam.put("propertyFacing", facing);
            postParam.put("Bathroom", bathrooms);
            postParam.put("propertyBedroom", bedrooms);
            postParam.put("Description", getText(description));
            postParam.put("Block", getText(block));
            postParam.put("streetName", getText(streetName));
            postParam.put("unitNo", getText(unitNo));
            postParam.put("postalCode", getText(postalCode));
            postParam.put("StorevHeight", storyHeight);
            postParam.put("propertyDistrict", district);
            postParam.put("price", getText(price));
            postParam.put("psf", getText(psf));

            postParam.put("agentId", global.getAgentId());
            postParam.put("thumbImage", thumbencodedString);
            postParam.put("galleryImage1", imgStringFile.size()>0? base64String(imgStringFile.get(0)) : "");
            postParam.put("galleryImage2", imgStringFile.size()>1? base64String(imgStringFile.get(1)) : "");
            postParam.put("galleryImage3", imgStringFile.size()>2? base64String(imgStringFile.get(2)) : "");
            postParam.put("buildIn", landedType.equals("6") ? getText(landSize) : "");
            postParam.put("landSize", landedType.equals("6") ? "" : getText(landSize));

            Log.d("propertyType", postParam.get("propertyType")+"");
            Log.d("propertyCategoryType", postParam.get("propertyCategoryType")+"");
            Log.d("title", postParam.get("title")+"");
            Log.d("propertyTenure", postParam.get("propertyTenure")+"");
            Log.d("propertyFacing", postParam.get("propertyFacing")+"");
            Log.d("Bathroom", postParam.get("Bathroom")+"");
            Log.d("propertyBedroom", postParam.get("propertyBedroom")+"");
            Log.d("Description", postParam.get("Description")+"");
            Log.d("Block", postParam.get("Block")+"");
            Log.d("streetName", postParam.get("streetName")+"");
            Log.d("unitNo", postParam.get("unitNo")+"");
            Log.d("postalCode", postParam.get("postalCode")+"");
            Log.d("propertyDistrict", postParam.get("propertyDistrict")+"");
            Log.d("price", postParam.get("price")+"");
            Log.d("psf", postParam.get("psf")+"");
            Log.d("agentId", postParam.get("agentId")+"");
            Log.d("thumbImage", postParam.get("thumbImage")+"");
            Log.d("galleryImage1", postParam.get("galleryImage1")+"");
            Log.d("buildIn", postParam.get("buildIn")+"");

            Log.d("imgStringFile", imgStringFile.toString()+"");
            ConnectionManager test = new ConnectionManager();
            try {
                test.connectionHandler(CreateListing.this,postParam,UrlUtils.CREATE_LISTING,ConnectionType.ConnectionTypePost,null,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                            try {
                                Log.d("object", response);
                                createList = new JSONObject(response);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                processdialog.dismiss();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                    }   
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                        processdialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CheckInternetDialog.class);
                        intent.putExtra("lowinternet", true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_SETTINGS);
                            error.printStackTrace();                                        
                        }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        processdialog.dismiss();
                        try{
                            if(createList.getString("status").equals("success")){
                                clearValues();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Property added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                galleryLayout.removeAllViews();
                                thumbLayout.removeAllViews();
                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.galleryPicker)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.thumbPicker)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                thumbencodedString="";
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CheckInternetDialog.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUESTCODE_SETTINGS);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

log

```
    11-25 13:22:50.863: D/propertyType(23118): 2
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/propertyCategoryType(23118): 1
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/title(23118): sampath property
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/propertyTenure(23118): 3
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/propertyFacing(23118): 2
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/Bathroom(23118): 6
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/propertyBedroom(23118): 5
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/Description(23118): created list
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/Block(23118): 35
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/streetName(23118): df street
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/unitNo(23118): 15
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/postalCode(23118): 123456
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/propertyDistrict(23118): 5
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/price(23118): 569846
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/psf(23118): 10.2347
11-25 13:22:50.863: D/agentId(23118): 98897777
11-25 13:22:50.878: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72775K, 50% free 82567K/162560K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
11-25 13:22:50.888: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 98.180MB for 17252360-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:50.918: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 39% free 99415K/162560K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): 1pWcbrW1rdNnJd32vby3d9WxMkSocOMqnKkfMyFsbO3Ax3xyOCQ2d6yZQWbjcpGxQc7v3j58vk9t
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): uAT1x1IIrMS2kO+Nwf3S8yYy3VsdTxJ1/M8fLuN3TraeMnKMVBG4bR8uCw8zqDyAOmeoyTmjo5Ja
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): u3TV6tK+vaLfbre28uPMuZfdbV6yS66bN+ltWkm/UfD0oDL8+MkINy9eWPyDJx1GO/ftiux+zkpk
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): AsAfmZht+UsQO5/vj35OSQWNcrodoqKh8syRjPKqV2/Meep/n0JHPOfQIsCJI16FAx3Lu3/M2cnn
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): U9/5gcgg12WpQtbvKpKvljyFKhly/wA+M+2M/XnP3uOmCxOUjywAY5II6Fvf/WfuyR6deckHJ2u9
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): P618vT8dWBR3OMsCzYAz8p53lxn9B/38XOSuTIGQYffkn7wAwzMCfbuP0wM5zTy6IkoIb5iOnyqV
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): y3+rwO2OTnPK5BAxUXl5I43bQGGPvfxexAyAucnueeCaRlVV6b8mn6627/P9BruzvlCuzaEIA+T/
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): AFjY7Z5/XJ9OXLJw43FjlmAA3Kp+Yc9+frxgHJANNBb5yihh8mBj765bPf0x3wAB1JwZUTaD8xXO
11-25 13:22:51.048: D/thumbImage(23118): GCZG1W+foD34Gf8AePXNBytttt6t/pf+vu3dwjkZI2zjYQi7sfd5Puc8Afr
11-25 13:22:51.068: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 39% free 99416K/162560K, paused 3ms+132ms, total 151ms
11-25 13:22:51.078: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 114.633MB for 17252360-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:51.113: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 16848K, 39% free 99415K/162560K, paused 18ms+4ms, total 36ms
11-25 13:22:51.113: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
11-25 13:22:51.113: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAwYECADASIA
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): EWPmVmUMJF7v/MDgnnGRn+9m+fcsPLkKhcFflz/GWO9+p7H6cccchsVVimYb2YqFf5fQ/f8AUZ4w
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): OvJyO4Bqdd4ycAjHOB8/zl/fPJHfJIxk5GDMropcFxtH3jjPmMN38H4DHJPr833mu3y4jG8EDDFu
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): vLe2ew/EgdTmgCa1C/vAhOJCnbnd8wHf/eznjp1wTWvbMQ03OX2qg/2uuPX04/Hg4OcSFwZvlHGE
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): AFjY7Z5/XJ9OXLJw43FjlmAA3Kp+Yc9+frxgHJANNBb5yihh8mBj765bPf0x3wAB1JwZUTaD8xXO
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/galleryImage1(23118): GCZG1W+foD34Gf8AePXNBytttt6t/pf+vu3dwjkZI2zjYQi7sfd5Puc8
11-25 13:22:51.248: D/imgStringFile(23118): [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/2013-01-01 08.02.07.jpg]
11-25 13:22:51.273: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16856K, 50% free 82575K/162560K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
11-25 13:22:51.278: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 98.187MB for 17252360-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:51.298: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 39% free 99423K/162560K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
11-25 13:22:51.323: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 39% free 99442K/162560K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 27ms
11-25 13:22:52.108: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8183K, 39% free 99443K/162560K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 65ms
11-25 13:22:52.853: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8186K, 39% free 99561K/162560K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 58ms
11-25 13:22:53.593: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8305K, 39% free 99448K/162560K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 62ms
11-25 13:22:54.333: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8191K, 39% free 99468K/162560K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 76ms
11-25 13:22:54.963: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8111K, 39% free 99450K/162560K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 39ms
11-25 13:22:55.673: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8065K, 39% free 99423K/162560K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
11-25 13:22:55.708: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 122.867MB for 25878536-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:55.793: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 16848K, 34% free 107847K/162560K, paused 67ms+4ms, total 83ms
11-25 13:22:55.793: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
11-25 13:22:55.793: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 16ms
11-25 13:22:56.303: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5757K, 34% free 107847K/162560K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
11-25 13:22:56.313: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 124.821MB for 19301052-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:56.343: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 23% free 126696K/162560K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
11-25 13:22:56.358: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 23% free 126696K/162560K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 16ms
11-25 13:22:56.358: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
11-25 13:22:56.388: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 143.228MB for 19301472-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:56.423: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25272K, 34% free 120272K/181412K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
11-25 13:22:56.448: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 34% free 120273K/181412K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 24ms
11-25 13:22:56.448: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
11-25 13:22:56.508: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 146.160MB for 28952204-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:56.563: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37697K, 48% free 110848K/209688K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
11-25 13:22:56.588: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 48% free 110848K/209688K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 25ms
11-25 13:22:56.588: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
11-25 13:22:56.593: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 125.798MB for 17252360-byte allocation
11-25 13:22:56.613: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 40% free 127696K/209688K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
11-25 13:22:56.653: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 59K, 40% free 127746K/209688K, paused 2ms+12ms, total 38ms
11-25 13:22:57.398: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8241K, 40% free 127696K/209688K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 58ms
11-25 13:22:57.398: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
11-25 13:22:58.103: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8178K, 40% free 127720K/209688K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 64ms
11-25 13:22:58.818: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8202K, 40% free 127720K/209688K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 61ms
11-25 13:22:59.523: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8203K, 40% free 127722K/209688K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 58ms
11-25 13:23:00.318: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8205K, 40% free 127724K/209688K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 65ms
11-25 13:23:00.998: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8046K, 40% free 127696K/209688K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
11-25 13:23:01.033: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 150.478MB for 25878536-byte allocation
11-25 13:23:01.058: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16848K, 36% free 136120K/209688K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
11-25 13:23:01.078: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 113K, 36% free 136142K/209688K, paused 1ms+6ms, total 19ms
11-25 13:23:01.553: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5644K, 36% free 136120K/209688K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
11-25 13:23:01.583: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 152.431MB for 19301052-byte allocation
11-25 13:23:01.668: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 27% free 154969K/209688K, paused 81ms, total 81ms
11-25 13:23:01.698: D/dalvikvm(23118): GC_CONCURRENT freed 25272K, 39% free 129697K/209688K, paused 4ms+8ms, total 32ms
11-25 13:23:01.698: D/dalvikvm(23118): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
11-25 13:23:01.713: I/dalvikvm-heap(23118): Grow heap (frag case) to 169.168MB for 43428302-byte allocation
11-25 13:23:53.318: D/object(23118): { "status": "success", "message" :"Property Listing Created Successfully."}
```

Comment: @Rohit have updated the logcat from server i am getting values as success but the values are inserted as 0 and null

Comment: m also facing this type of problem from 2 days , see my 1 answer and maybe it will helps .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113967/how-to-use-to-send-data-in-android/20115354#20115354